# Saving Bitmaps In a list always return the same image

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Im creating a `CTRL + Z undo` feature for a image editor, each click on the screen will save a image with this code:

```
Private Sub SaveMap(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Dim asd As New Bitmap(Form6.PictureBox1.Image)
    GlobalVariables.BackUp.Add(Form6.PictureBox1.Image)
    asd.Dispose()
End Sub
```

and everytime the user press `CTRL + Z` this code will be executed

```
Private Sub Picturebox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Z And e.Control Then
        GlobalVariables.BackUp.RemoveAt(GlobalVariables.BackUp.Count - 1)
        Form6.PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(GlobalVariables.BackUp.Last)
        Form6.PictureBox1.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

But seens that All the bitmaps im saving in the `Public Shared BackUp As New List(Of Bitmap)` are the same.

Because no matter which index i return with `GlobalVariables.BackUp.Item()` , every of them return the exact same image.

Why are the bitmaps on the list getting replaced, and not added one after another?

Comment: you arent savng a bitmap to the list, but a reference to the picturebox image.  when that image changes, so does what you saved because it is simply a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving a new bitmap, but a reference to the picturebox.image.  As a **reference**, it will change when the `PictureBox.Image` changes.  This should save a new image to the list by cloning what is currently displayed:

```
Private Sub SaveMap(ByVal sender ...
    Dim bmp As Bitmap
    bmp = Form6.PictureBox1.Image.Clone   ' clone the image

    GlobalVariables.BackUp.Add(bmp)       ' save the copy

    ' dispose of it later when you remove it from the list
End Sub
```

Comment: tried in 3 different ways: `Dim asd As New Bitmap(Form6.PictureBox1.Image.Clone)`Gives me error "new cannot be called without a narrowing conversion", `Dim asd As Bitmap              asd = Form6.PictureBox1.Image.Clone` gives me a null object error once i try to get it from the list, and the code that you gave me says that "No accessible New accepts this number of arguments", what is wrong?

Comment: sorry, copy error; you dont need `New` on the bmp declaration - `Clone` will create a New one.  you will want to check that there is an image in the PicBox to avoid a NullReferenceException

Comment: I put the code inside a try/catch and it gives me this error: http://pokit.org/get/img/ec2169b21247497f4347ca4c0d788953.jpg what is happening?

Comment: not sure, I dont speak that language to know which line, but it is something different than your original question.  I have no idea what/how the images are stored - looks like more than a `List(of Bitmap)` which doesn't have a `Last` prop; and the List doesnt need to be Shared.

Comment: oh i see, thanks by your info then, you put me in the right way now im gonna discover what else is wrong :) thanks

Comment: it turns out that i failed to see your instrunctions and the problem was caused because i was disposing the image right after adding it to the list, and not after deleting, problem fixed